# Choosing the numbering of proposition, assumptions, and corollary, etc

Tags: numbering, theorems

I have the following output

[image]

But I would like to have them stated **Assumption 1** and **Proposition 1** instead. I am using the following in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %the depth of section numbering 0 means no numbering of any section, sub-section and on.
%used for begining theorems and propostions numbered according to the section they are in
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]% theorem counter resets every \subsection
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}% Remove subsection from theorem counter representation
\newtheorem{proposition}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{assumption}[thm]{Assumption}}
```

This is basically the part of my test document:

```
\begin{assumption}
    \label{Assumption 1}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.7\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item[i)] 
            \item[ii)] 
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{assumption}

\begin{proposition}
    \label{P1}
    Proposition...
\end{proposition}
\noindent {\it Proof}. See Appendix \ref{proofs}. $\blacksquare$
```

What I would like is it to have the Assumptions numbered by the Assumptions. For example **Assumption 2** follows after **Assumption 1**. And Propositions numbered by Propositions: **Proposition 1**, **Proposition 2**, and so on. Similar idea for Corollaries and Lemmas, etc. How do I achieve this?

Comment: By using a common reference counter (here `[thm]`) you are asking that the same counter be used for all theorem-class objects.  What you really want is for each particular type of object to use its own counter, as `\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[subsection] \renewcommand{\theproposition}{\arabic{proposition}}` and similarly for each type of object.

Answer (score 1):

From the above comment, the following in the preamble fixes the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %the depth of section numbering 0 means no numbering of any section, sub-section and on.
%used for begining theorems and propostions numbered according to the section they are in
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]% theorem counter resets every \subsection
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}% Remove subsection from theorem counter representation 
%Numbers the propositions, lemmas, corollaries, etc within themselves
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[subsection] \renewcommand{\theproposition}{\arabic{proposition}}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}[subsection]  \renewcommand{\theassumption}{\arabic{assumption}}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[subsection] 
\renewcommand{\thelemma}{\arabic{lemma}}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[subsection] \renewcommand{\thecorollary}{\arabic{corollary}}
```